# inverse of GRANT ALL PRIVILIGES

Tags: mysql, sql

What syntax would you use to reverse the following statement in MySQL 5.6?

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to root@mydomain.com IDENTIFIED BY 'YYYY' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Assume that a typo was made, and you just want to reverse all effects of the statement and start over with a properly typed version with no typos.

Comment: Being that this has to do with privileges, you might find more help on the DBA Stack Exchange...

Comment: I think it might be `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES`

Comment: My parents always just grounded me.

Comment: @codemed - I was doing it off the top of my head - it is easy to look up revoke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opposite of `GRANT` is `REVOKE`.

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* FROM root@mydomain.com;
```

Note that this won't revert you back to the set of privileges it had before you did the erroneous `GRANT`. It will remove all privileges from this user, and you'll need to add back the privileges you want.

If you want to get rid of the user entirely, use `DROP USER`:

```
DROP USER root@mydomain.com;
```

Comment: Added `DROP USER` to the answer. Are you having trouble reading the MySQL manual sections on managing users and privileges?

Comment: Thank you and +1 for answering the question quickly.